# Json C# add in the variable to the json string

Tags: c#, json

I want to add my string username and password into the string jsonData however there seems to be an error.

```
public async Task<string> authLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.20.129.193/");

        string jsonData = @"{""AdminNo"" : """+username+""", """+password+""" : ""password""}";

        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("NYPStudentLifeService/api/student/login",content);

        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using is wrong try out this method. Also the password order was wrong as mentioned above. ^

Instead of:

```
string jsonData = @"{""AdminNo"" : """+username+""", ""password"" : """+password+"""}";
```

You can try out this:

```
string jsonData = @"{'AdminNo':'"+username+"','Password':'"+password+"'}";
```

Comment: you can do this way too.

string jsonData = @"{""AdminNo"" : """+username+""", ""password"" : ""pass""}";
jsonData = jsonData.Replace("pass", Passwrd);

Answer (score 0):

Use RestSharp for REST API calls and NewtoSoft to serialize your objects to JSONs. Your code is obsolete.

http://restsharp.org/

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

By the way... your error is the order of "password"

You have

```
string jsonData = @"{""AdminNo"" : """+username+""", """+password+""" : ""password""}";
```

Should be

```
string jsonData = @"{""AdminNo"" : """+username+""", ""password"" : """+password+"""}";
```